# Jquery form plug in issue on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using JQuery Form plugin. In IE9, Sometimes I am getting "SCRIPT5: Access Denied" error on console.It works on Mozilla and Chrome.
here is my code:

Form: its a hidden form on my view and i am submitting this form on onchange event of file type input control.

```
<form id="fileAttachment" action="@Url.Action("AttachFile", "Attachment")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" onChange="submitFormOnFileSelection()"/>
    <input type="submit" id="xxx" name="asd" />
</form>
```

Code to submit form:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {

            },
            success: function () {

            },
            complete: function(response) {
                $("#AttachmentArea").html(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#AttachmentArea").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");
            }

        };
        $("#fileAttachment").ajaxForm(options);

    });

function submitFormOnFileSelection() {

        if ($("#upload").val() != '') {
            $('#fileAttachment').submit(function() {
                $("#fileAttachment").ajaxSubmit(options);
            });
            $("#upload").val('');
        }
    }
```

Problem occurs on IE9??

thanks for help.

Comment: What piece of javascript does "SCRIPT5: Access Denied" points to ?

Comment: @karthik problem is with form.submit in jqueryform.js..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this $("#upload").val('') with file inputs in ie. The right way to clear it is to replace input with new one.

```
$("#upload").replaceWith('<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" onChange="submitFormOnFileSelection()"/>');
```

Comment: thanks, will do that. but actually problem is with formsubmit.. it doesn't post form to server on IE9. but works fine with other browsers.